# Why isn't my terminal running my updated C++ code?

Tags: c++, terminal

I am a new programmer and I am trying to use the terminal on my Mac to compile and run the C++ code I write using the Sublime text editor.

I am able to get my code to run using the terminal, however, whenever I make changes to my code on sublime and then re-compile it on my terminal, my terminal doesn't recognize my changes and keeps on running my original code.

Does anyone know what might be happening?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please put your terminal output and the commands you are trying to run.

Answer (score 5):

I can think of two *possibilities* that spring immediately to mind. If you're changing your code in the editor, and that's *not* being reflected in the compilation, then it's likely to be one of the following. Either:

- you're not saving the file in the location you think you are; or
- you're not saving the file at *all.*

The easiest way to tell if one of these is the case is to introduce an error into your code<sup>(a)</sup>, like:

```
int my hovercraft = full of eels;
```

and make sure the compiler complains about it.

If you're not saving it at all, do so. If you're saving it in the wrong place, you can usually find out *where* just by doing a `Save As` and seeing where the default location is.

---

If you're annoyed that you have to save, and that computers should just "work"<sup>(b)</sup>, Sublime Text has an [auto-save feature that may come in handy, courtesy of one Lucy Bain](https://lucybain.com/resources/setting-up-sublime-autosave/). Instructions (paraphrased) are duplicated here in case that site ever disappears:

1. Open Sublime
2. Find `Settings` and edit the user window (under `Sublime Text 2 > Preferences` for Mac, just `Preferences` for Windows).
3. Add the line `"save_on_focus_lost": true`.
4. Save and close the file.

At that point, whenever you click away from a particular file, it should save it.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Some developers seem to have little trouble doing this without even *trying* :-)

<sup>(b)</sup> A not unreasonable expectation for a Mac user :-)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think my problem was that it wasn't saving, so I'll be sure to set up that auto-save feature.